# If table exists drop table then create it, if it does not exist just create it

Tags: mysql

I'm stumped, I don't know how to go about doing this.

Basically I just want to create a table, but if it exists it needs to be dropped and re-created, not truncated, but if it doesn't exist just create it.

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: @Shomz, That's what they wanted. Yet the existence of this question and the 20k views to this page proves that that's about as easy as converting the English into Greek.

Comment: @Pacerier Couldn't agree more: `διαγραφή πίνακα, εφόσον υπάρχει`.

Comment: @Shomz, There's a grammar error.

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Just put `` DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablename`; `` before your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

That statement drops the table if it exists but will not throw an error if it does not.

Comment: Thanks! This also works for a list of tables or views! `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'table1', 'table2';` and `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS 'view1', 'view2';` PS- What witchcraft did you use to have `s in inline code!?

Comment: @Campbeln Just double up the backticks before and after the code segment. Single backticks are then shown verbatim.

Answer (score 59):

Just use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `foo`;
CREATE TABLE `foo` ( ... );
```

Try searching the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html) first if you have any other problems.

Answer (score 22):

Well... Huh. For years nobody mentioned one subtle thing.

Despite `` DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bla`; CREATE TABLE `bla` ( ... ); `` seems reasonable, it leads to a situation when old table is already gone and new one has not been yet created: some client may try to access subject table right at this moment.

The better way is to create brand new table and swap it with an old one (table contents are lost):

```
CREATE TABLE `bla__new` (id int); /* if not ok: terminate, report error */
RENAME TABLE `bla__new` to `bla`; /* if ok: terminate, report success */
RENAME TABLE `bla` to `bla__old`, `bla__new` to `bla`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bla__old`;
```

- You should check the result of `CREATE ...` and do not continue *in
  case of error*, because failure means that other thread didn't finish
  the same script: either because it crashed in the middle or just
  didn't finish yet -- it's a good idea to inspect things by yourself.
- Then, you should check the result of first `RENAME ...` and do not
  continue *in case of success*: whole operation is successfully
  completed; even more, running next `RENAME ...` can (and will) be
  unsafe if another thread has already started same sequence (it's
  better to cover this case than not to cover, see locking note below).
- Second `RENAME ...` atomically replaces table definition, refer to
  [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/rename-table.html)
  for details.
- At last, `DROP ...` just cleans up the old table,
  obviously.

Wrapping all statements with something like `SELECT GET_LOCK('__upgrade', -1); ... DO RELEASE_LOCK('__upgrade');` allows to just invoke all statements sequentially without error checking, but I don't think it's a good idea: complexity increases and locking functions in MySQL aren't safe for statement-based replication.

If the table data should survive table definition upgrade... For general case it's far more complex story about comparing table definitions to find out differences and produce proper `ALTER ...` statement, which is not always possible automatically, e.g. when columns are renamed.

**Side note 1:**
You can deal with views using the same approach, in this case `CREATE/DROP TABLE` merely transforms to `CREATE/DROP VIEW` while `RENAME TABLE` remains unchanged. In fact you can even turn table into view and vice versa.

```
CREATE VIEW `foo__new` as ...; /* if not ok: terminate, report error */
RENAME TABLE `foo__new` to `foo`; /* if ok: terminate, report success */
RENAME TABLE `foo` to `foo__old`, `foo__new` to `foo`;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `foo__old`;
```

**Side note 2:**
MariaDB users should be happy with `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE/VIEW`, which already cares about subject problem and it's fine points.

Comment: Excellent solution! Instead of having to check an operation halfway through, wouldn't it be possible to ``CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (ignore int)`` first, so then the first rename is unnecessary? The second rename will always work then, and either the current table or the dummy table will be deleted at the end of the query.

Comment: It seems reasonable, but in fact this way needs more actions to complete for generic case (which assumes that the whole system is not in "recovery needed" state).

Comment: When using MariaDB's [CREATE OR REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#create-or-replace), be aware that it behaves like `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo; CREATE TABLE foo ...`, so if the server crashes between `DROP` and `CREATE`, the table will have been dropped, but not recreated, and you're left with no table at all. I advise you to use the renaming method described above instead until `CREATE OR REPLACE` has become [atomic](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/atomic-ddl/).

Answer (score 3):

I needed to drop a table and re-create with a data from a view.
I was creating a table out of a view and this is what I did:

```
DROP TABLE <table_name>;
CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS SELECT * FROM <view>;
```

The above worked for me using MySQL MariaDb.

Comment: drop table table_name;                                                                                                                                 create table as select * from the view;

Comment: If you are on MariaDB (MySQL lacks this), then you can simply `CREATE OR REPLACE <table_name> AS SELECT * FROM <view>;`