# How can I drop table only if exists

Tags: mysql, sql

How can we create a table though if exists in MySql.
I want to create  a table if exists then drop it, and create it.
In other words, i want to do these two queries atomically.

```
drop table if exists `tbl_Name`;

create table `tbl_Name` (c1 int, c2 text);
```

**we can not sure that the sequence of those two queries will up to down.

thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is. Those are valid statements...

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Run the two queries from the *same* MySQL connection, one after the other, connected as a user with the required privileges. MySQL will return an error condition if either of those statements doesn't succeed for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If table exists drop table then create it, if it does not exist just create it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155989/if-table-exists-drop-table-then-create-it-if-it-does-not-exist-just-create-it)

Comment: if there is a requirement for this to be "atomic" as you answer below please edit the question to make that clear.  And IMHO that could easily be controlled by using a transaction - everything in a transaction is atomic.

Comment: @Barry: transactions apply to DML statements, not to DDL in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL [DROP TABLE IF EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_Name;

CREATE TABLE tbl_Name (
  c1       INT,
  c2       TEXT
);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. i tested this, but it is not Atomic. Also it my be not run correctly in multi processor servers. i tested and i had this error: "Error Code: 1050. Table 'tbl_Name' already exists"

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I cant help you further more then that:) @user2352554

Comment: A multiprocessor server shouldn't be a problem. As long as those two queries are executed in the same MySQL session, one after the other, just as sagi has outline hered. There should be no race condition in the MySQL server. (The DROP STATEMENT may wait, if the table is currently in use. The statement may return an error, for example, if the user doesn't have privileges to drop the table.)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[YourTable]') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[YourTable]
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL all data definition statements (such as create or drop table) are run [in their own, specific transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html):

> The intent is to handle each such statement in its own special transaction because it cannot be rolled back anyway.

Your issue is not that these statements are not executed in an atomic way, your problem is that a create table statement may be executed before the corresponding drop table is executed because of parallel execution of instructions. In this case you either

1. Need to enforce serialization of drop table - create table command pairs
2. Or you use [create table if not exists tablename](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) version of the create table command:

> The keywords IF NOT EXISTS prevent an error from occurring if the table exists. However, there is no verification that the existing table has a structure identical to that indicated by the CREATE TABLE statement.

However, even if you used the latter one, you still have to make sure, that there is no subsequent drop table statement that would remove your nicely created table. Pls also note that if not exists purely checks the table name, but does not check the table structure!

So, to be honest, I would go with option 1: you must serialise the execution of DDL statements.