# Teradata: replace an existing table with "CREATE TABLE"

Tags: sql, settings, teradata

What setting should I change to make Teradata replace existing tables with `CREATE TABLE` query?
Currently, if the table exists, an attemps to `CREATE` it results in error. So I have to `DROP` the table before CREATing it.

thx

Comment: You can't as far as i know. To re-create a table you MUST drop it first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If table exists drop table then create it, if it does not exist just create it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155989/if-table-exists-drop-table-then-create-it-if-it-does-not-exist-just-create-it)

Comment: @Wndrr: This is a MySQL extension which is not supported in Teradata. But it can be emulated using a Stored Procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771103/2527905

Comment: Of course you might simply ignore the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DROP_IF_EXISTS(IN table_name VARCHAR(60),IN db_name VARCHAR(60))
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbc.tables WHERE databasename=db_name AND tablename=table_name) 
  THEN
    CALL DBC.SysExecSQL('DROP TABLE ' || db_name ||'.'|| table_name);
  END IF;
END;
```

And in your DDL script:

```
call drop_if_exists('$your_table_name','$your_db_name')
;
database $your_db_name;
create table $your_table_name ...
;
```

Comment: You must add `AND TableKind = 'T'` and better use `dbc.TablesV` (plus VARCHAR(128)). But it's more efficient to simply drop the table and ignore the *table doesn't exist* error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771103/2527905