# Replacing a table if another table exists

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables:

1. 'table_a'
2. 'table_b' which contains updated content of 'table_a'.

I want 'table_b' to replace 'table_a' and be called 'table_a', but only if 'table_b' exists. Otherwise, do nothing.

I have tried using a combination of `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a` and `RENAME TABLE table_b TO table_a` without any success.

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Look at Alex Offshore's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155989/if-table-exists-drop-table-then-create-it-if-it-does-not-exist-just-create-it/20156024

Comment: Thanks. That's as good an explanation as I've come across. It should help me on the correct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to:

```
rename table table_a to table_old, table_b to table_a;
```

And catch the error. If `table_b` doesn't exist, neither of the renames is executed.

If its successful, you'll need to remove `table_old` otherwise it will still be around:

```
MariaDB [test]> show tables
    -> ;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| table_a        |
| table_b        |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> rename table table_a to table_old, table_b to table_a;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)

MariaDB [test]> drop table table_old;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [test]> rename table table_a to table_old, table_b to table_a;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.table_b' doesn't exist

MariaDB [test]> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| table_a        |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: I do like simple, and catching errors is always easier than predicting them.